# Arduino Vending Machine problem

Tags: arduino-uno

Currently I'm working on a vending machine project. The vending machine works using 3 button on LCD Keypad Shield DFRobot where 1 button of it assigned as 0.10 cent,the other two 0.20 cent and 0.50 cent respectively. My problem here is how can my system keep track on the balance/coin inserted so that whenever I pressed `button 1 = balance 0.10` then later I pressed `button 2 = balance 0.30` (because 0.20 cent added to the system). Or if you have a better idea for my code, that should be great. This is my code so far:

```cpp
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
    LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    int lcd_key     = 0;
    int adc_key_in  = 0;
    #define btnRIGHT  0
    #define btnUP     1
    #define btnDOWN   2
    #define btnLEFT   3
    #define btnSELECT 4
    #define btnNONE   5
    volatile float balance = 0.00;
    float number1 = 0.10;
    float number2 = 0.20;
    float number3 = 0.50;
    int read_LCD_buttons()
    {
    adc_key_in = analogRead(0);      // read the value from the sensor 
    if (adc_key_in > 1000) return btnNONE; 
    if (adc_key_in < 50)   return btnRIGHT;  
    if (adc_key_in < 195)  return btnUP; 
    if (adc_key_in < 380)  return btnDOWN; 
    if (adc_key_in < 555)  return btnLEFT; 
    if (adc_key_in < 790)  return btnSELECT;   
    return btnNONE;  
    }

    void setup()
    {
    lcd.begin(16, 2);            
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("TouchNGo Machine"); 
    }

    void loop()
    {
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);         
    lcd.print("Balance=");      
    lcd.setCursor(10,1);           
    lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons(); 
    balance = 0.00 ;

    switch(lcd_key)
    {
    case(btnLEFT):
    {
    balance = balance + number1  ;
    lcd.print("RM");
    lcd.println(balance);
    break;
    }
    case(btnRIGHT):
    {
    balance = balance + number2 ;

    lcd.print("RM");
    lcd.println(balance);
    break;
    }
    case(btnUP):
    {
    balance = balance + number3  ;
    lcd.print("RM");
    lcd.println(balance);
    break;
    }
    }
    }
```

I would love to hear any comment from you guys.Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "balance = 0.0;" from you main loop.  It's always clearing your balance.